# Installing docker on Raspberry PI 3

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, update, docker

I'm getting the following trying to run docker on a Rasperry PI 3.  [Link to the the instructions I used](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-on-raspberry-pi).

```
Setting up docker-ce (5:19.03.8~3-0~raspbian-stretch) ...
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-03-30 06:44:11 UTC; 51ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 28613 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 28613 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CPU: 638ms

Mar 30 06:44:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed …te.
Mar 30 06:44:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result '…e'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libicu57:armhf (57.1-6+deb9u4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem is that you just did an `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` without rebooting afterwards. Simply run `sudo reboot now` and you can run `get-docker.sh` again.